# Golang Martini Templates Just Showing HTML when Rendering Markdown

Tags: html, templates, go, markdown, martini

I am working on writing a simple blog in Golang using Martini, the Martini-Contrib Renderer package, and Blackfriday.

I am able to get the post into the DB and out of the DB with no issues. I even get the Body of the post out of the DB and into my struct as html however when we render the template the output is just plain text html and not looking pretty like it should.

Code is hosted here:

http://bitbucket.org/ChasingLogic/goblog

Any help would be great.

EDIT:

You can see what it's doing here:

http://chasinglogic.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Golang templates escape variables by default.  You can use `template.HTML` instead of `string` when it contains HTML and the source is trusted (which, in this instance, it seems to be).

http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#HTML

> type HTML string
>
> HTML encapsulates a known safe HTML document fragment. It should not be used for HTML from a third-party, or HTML with unclosed tags or comments. The outputs of a sound HTML sanitizer and a template escaped by this package are fine for use with HTML.

The way I would fix it would be by changing this

```
type Post struct {
  Title  string
  Body   string
  Author string
  Date   string
}
```

to

```
type Post struct {
  Title  string
  Body   template.HTML
  Author string
  Date   string
}
```

And then change

```
post.Body = string(blackfriday.MarkdownCommon([]byte(preFormatMarkdown)))
```

to

```
post.Body = template.HTML(blackfriday.MarkdownCommon([]byte(preFormatMarkdown)))
```